# rewrite rule for codeigniter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

this is my controller in CI

```
class Welcome extends Controller {

 function Welcome()
 {
  parent::Controller(); 
  }

 function index()
 {

 }
 function bil($model='')
 { }
```

I want to do a rewrite so that

```
http://example.com/index.php/welcome/bil/model
```

becomes

```
http://example.com/model
```

in my htaccess I have

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/welcome/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/welcome/bil/$1 [L]
```

I thought it should be as easy as removing the /index.php/welcome/ part
but when I uncomment the last line it get **500 internal server error**

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use mod_rewrite to remove your index.php file like you have above, but use [CodeIgniter's routing features](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) to reroute `example.com/model` to `example.com/welcome/bil/model`.

In your routes.php configuration file, you can then define a new route like this:

```
// a URL with anything after example.com 
// will get remapped to the "welcome" class and the "bil" function, 
// passing the match as a variable
$route['(:any)'] = "welcome/bil/$1";
```

So then, typing `example.com/abc123` would be equivalent to `example.com/welcome/bil/abc123`.

Note that only characters permitted by `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` (which is located in your config.php file) are allowed in a URL.

Hope that helps!